# Is there a good automated way to make a generic block of text square?

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I often take long equations from Mathematica that are too long to ever be readable and bring them into C.  Mathematica puts in a lot of newlines that I want to get rid of such that it fits nicely into a block of 80-character lines.

For example:

```
(sin(T)*(16*pow(a,2)*M*cos(T)*pow(r,5)*
        pow(Th_d,2) - 
       8*pow(a,2)*cos(T)*pow(r,6)*pow(Th_d,2) + 
       M*pow(r,3)*(-((3*pow(a,2)*pow(Ee,2) - 8*pow(Jz,2) - 
                4*pow(a,2)*pow(Ee,2)*cos(2*T) + 
                pow(a,2)*pow(Ee,2)*cos(4*T))*Cot(T)*pow(csc(T),3))/
           2. + 32*pow(a,4)*pow(cos(T),3)*pow(Th_d,2)) - 
       2*(pow(a,4)*pow(Jz,2)*cos(T)*pow(Cot(T),4) + 
          4*pow(a,6)*pow(cos(T),5)*pow(r_d,2) + 
          4*pow(a,8)*pow(cos(T),5)*pow(Th_d,2)) - 
       2*pow(r,4)*(pow(Jz,2)*Cot(T)*pow(csc(T),3) + 
          4*pow(a,2)*cos(T)*pow(r_d,2) + 
          2*pow(a,4)*(5*cos(T) + cos(3*T))*pow(Th_d,2))\
        + (pow(a,2)*M*Cot(T)*pow(csc(T),3)*r*
          (4*(pow(a,2)*pow(Ee,2) - 2*a*Ee*Jz + 2*pow(Jz,2))*cos(2*T) - 
            a*Ee*(a*Ee - 2*Jz)*(3 + cos(4*T)) + 
            2*pow(a,4)*pow(sin(2*T),4)*pow(Th_d,2)))/2. + 
       pow(r,2)*(-16*pow(a,4)*pow(cos(T),3)*
           pow(r_d,2) - 
          4*pow(a,2)*pow(Cot(T),3)*csc(T)*
           (pow(Jz,2) + pow(a,4)*(5 + cos(2*T))*pow(sin(T),4)*
              pow(Th_d,2)))))/
   (4.*pow(pow(a,2)*pow(cos(T),2) + pow(r,2),2)*
     (pow(a,2) - 2*M*r + pow(r,2)))
```

would become

```
(sin(T)*(16*pow(a,2)*M*cos(T)*pow(r,5)*pow(Th_d,2) - 8*pow(a,2)*cos(T)*
pow(r,6)*pow(Th_d,2) + M*pow(r,3)*(-((3*pow(a,2)*pow(Ee,2) - 8*pow(Jz,2) - 
4*pow(a,2)*pow(Ee,2)*cos(2*T) + pow(a,2)*pow(Ee,2)*cos(4*T))*Cot(T)*pow(csc(T),3))/
2. + 32*pow(a,4)*pow(cos(T),3)*pow(Th_d,2)) - 2*(pow(a,4)*pow(Jz,2)*cos(T)*
pow(Cot(T),4) + 4*pow(a,6)*pow(cos(T),5)*pow(r_d,2) + 4*pow(a,8)*pow(cos(T),5)*
pow(Th_d,2)) - 2*pow(r,4)*(pow(Jz,2)*Cot(T)*pow(csc(T),3) + 4*pow(a,2)*cos(T)*
pow(r_d,2) + 2*pow(a,4)*(5*cos(T) + cos(3*T))*pow(Th_d,2)) + (pow(a,2)*M*Cot(T)*
pow(csc(T),3)*r*(4*(pow(a,2)*pow(Ee,2) - 2*a*Ee*Jz + 2*pow(Jz,2))*cos(2*T) - 
a*Ee*(a*Ee - 2*Jz)*(3 + cos(4*T)) + 2*pow(a,4)*pow(sin(2*T),4)*pow(Th_d,2)))/2. + 
pow(r,2)*(-16*pow(a,4)*pow(cos(T),3)*pow(r_d,2) - 4*pow(a,2)*pow(Cot(T),3)*csc(T)*
(pow(Jz,2) + pow(a,4)*(5 + cos(2*T))*pow(sin(T),4)*pow(Th_d,2)))))/(4.*pow(pow(a,2)*
pow(cos(T),2) + pow(r,2),2)*(pow(a,2) - 2*M*r + pow(r,2)));
```

It's not the most important thing, but it would cut down on code length, and is much nicer to work with for big files.

Comment: Try this (ymmv): `perl -0777 -pe 's/(?:\\?\s)+/ /g;s/(.{1,78})(?:\s|(?<=\))|(?=\())/\1\n/g'` (this should only break lines on spaces and before and after parentheses).

Comment: Or break on parens, spaces and commas: `perl -0777 -pe 's/(?:\\?\s)+/ /g;s/(.{1,78})(?:\s|(?<=[(),])|(?=[(),]))/\1\n/g'`. Hopefully this is safe (just splitting on a word boundary isn't, because it can break floating point numbers like `2.` or `2.5`).

Comment: A generic block of text can be easily made to fit in 80-character lines: `tr -s '[[:space:]]' ' ' | fold -w 80`, but that might break the line in unsuitable places .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`, you could do

```
sed -E 'N;s/(.*)(\n) */\2\1/;/.{81}/s_^(.)(.{,79}[-+/*]) *_\2\1_;/^\n/!P;D' filename
```

- `-E` is for using extended regular expressions, making it easier to read
- `N` adds the next line to the buffer
- `s/(.*)(\n) */\2\1/` joins the lines, moving the newline to the beginning and removing indenting whitespaces
- `/.{81}/` is valid for lines with more than 80 chars; in this case, execute `s_^(.)(.{,79}[-+/*]) *_\2\1_` to move the line break to the last symbol
- `/^\n/!P` if the first line in the buffer is not empty, print it
- `D` start over with the rest of the buffer

As pointed out by mosvy, this script has a problem with trailing backslashes in a line, so those should probably be removed with `s/\\$//`. Also, if there could be longer input lines (which is not the OP's problem, but maybe some future reader), one could replace the `N` by `/.{80}/!N`. So the whole script would be

```
sed -E 's/\\$//;/.{80}/!N;s/(.*)(\n) */\2\1/;/.{81}/s_^(.)(.{,79}[-+/*]) *_\2\1_;/^\n/!P;D' filename
```

Comment: Easier with GNU `sed -E ':1;N;s/\n *//;/.{80}/s_^.{,79}[-+/*] *_&\n_;/\n/!b1;P;D'` (newline in replacement, labels terminated by `;`)

Comment: thanks so much! this is perfect.

Comment: Besides assuming that the lines are not already longer than 80 characters, this could break floating point numbers written in scientific notation: `printf '(sin(T)*(16*pow(a,2)*M*cos(T)*pow(r,5)* pow(Th_d,2)\n- 8*pow(a,2)*cos(T)*pow(r,6e-1)
*pow(Th_d,2)))' | sed -E your_script`. It also leaves the backslash in (as `\+`, which is not valid C. All this may or may not be a problem depending on the format of the input data, and how the output is supposed to be used.

Comment: @mosvy Thank you, I updated the answer to take into account your remarks (except for the scientific notation -- you'd need a real parser to distinguise `e+42` being part of a scientific notation and adding 42 to a variable `e`. No quick-and-dirty regexp job).